# Centrar horizontalmente botón

Tags: html, css

Queria consultarles como hago para alinear mi botón al centro o si se puede establecer coordenadas precisas para alinearlo.Les dejo una parte de mi codigo :
Html:

```
<a class="boton_personalizado"  href="aqui la direcc">Soy un botón</a>
```

css:

```
 .boton_personalizado{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 2px solid #EDD8D8;


  }
  .boton_personalizado:hover{
    color: #EDD8D8;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
```

Comment: Con Ibuprofeno cada 8 horas

Comment: Alinear al centro vertical u horizontalmente?

Comment: Horizontalmente

Comment: Ponlo dentro de un `div` y usas css con `position: absolute`

Comment: Bueno también verticalmente si se puede .

Answer (score 3):

Tomemos en cuenta lo siguiente:

- Lo que tratas de centrar horizontalmente es un elemento *en línea*
- La propiedad que *pudiera auxiliarnos* es [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) con un valor de `center`
- El problema es que esta propiedad trabaja para la distribución horizontal de los elementos de tipo *en bloque* como puedes leer en el enlace provisto mas arriba

Dados los puntos anteriores, la opción mas simple es meter dentro de un elemento en bloque como un `p` a tu etiqueta `a` y que el centrado se aplique al primero mencionado y en concencuencia afecte a su contenido o etiqueta interna.

```html
    <style>
      #centrado {
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
    
    <p id="centrado">
      <a href="#">Ir a ningún lugar</a>
    </p>
```

**Lectura altamente recomendada**

- [Alineación y justificación](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#justification)

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo usar un codigo más sencillo, puedes hacerlo agregando en el "" dos lineas de código que hacen referencia a los archivos de CSS y JS de Bootrap, con el fin que lo hagas de una forma mas sencilla con clases de Bootstrap.

Te recomiendo hacerlo de esta forma, ya los estilos se los puede aplicar en el CSS como tu gustes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        
        <title>Titulo web</title>

        <!--  CSS Bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!--  JS Bootstrap -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center " id="boton">
            <a class="btn btn-primary">Soy un botón</a>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

En teoría lo que hice fue, a la etiqueta  le aplique las clases "btn btn-primary", luego encerré esa etiqueta  dentro de un  que lleva un ID el cual podrás usar en el CSS para aplicar los estilos personalizados que desees, al  le puse unas clases de Bootstrap "d-flex justify-content-center" y de esta manera el botón ya está centrado Horizontalmente.

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Aplica flexbox a la etiqueta padre en la que vayas a poner a tu enlace

html:

```
<div>
   <a class="boton_personalizado"  href="aqui la direcc">Soy un botón</a>
</div>
```

css:

```
div{
  border:1px solid;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

De esta manera quedará centrado horizontal y verticalmente, pero ojo porque aplicará para todos los elementos dentro del div y el centro se calculará en base al tamaño del mismo.